# String extends Function?

Tags: typescript, types

I ran into a typing problem after upgrading a library. This is the distilled form of the bug:

```
class Bar {
  id: string = '';
}

declare type ExcludeFunctions<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends Function ? never : (K extends symbol ? never : K);


declare type Baz<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as ExcludeFunctions<T, K>]?: T[K];
};


class Base<T extends Bar> {

  public async foo(input: Baz<T>) {
   //Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Baz<T>'.
    input.id = 'x';
  }
}
```

Why doesn't Baz have property 'id'? It looks like "string extends Function" evaluates to true, because when I remove this condition the error disappears. But string clearly doesn't extend Function. What is going on here?

Comment: It's definitely not that `string` extends `Function`, as you can easily see by doing `type Q = Baz<Bar>;` and looking at `Q` ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqEXrm)). It has to do with generics. (What, specifically, I don't know.)

Comment: But if i declare ExcludeFunctions like this:
`declare type ExcludeFunctions<T, K extends keyof T> = K extends symbol ? never : K;`
it compiles

Comment: `declare type ExcludeFunctions<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends Function ? K : (K extends symbol ? never : K);` fails for me too, so that can't be it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fairly sure that this is a limitation with generics and the fact that you are losing context when you say that `T` in `Base<T>` must extend `Bar`.  When you pass the generic into `Baz`, it is using mapped types so it cannot compute through the `Bar` part of `T` because `T` could be anything that extends `Bar`.  You can fix this error by changing the type of `input` to specifically compute `Baz<Bar>` to `Baz<T> & Baz<Bar>`:

```
class Bar {
  id: string = '';
}

type Baz<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Function ? never : K]?: T[K];
};

class Base<T extends Bar> {

  public async foo(input: Baz<T> & Baz<Bar>) {
    type Debug = Baz<T>;
    //   ^? type Debug = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Function ? never : K]?: T[K] | undefined; }

    input.id = 'x'; // no error!
  }
}
```

Also note how `Baz<T & Bar>` does not work because that is the same thing as saying `Baz<T>` because `T` must extend `Bar`.

P.S. You shouldn't use `declare type` as types are already in an ambient context.

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCYCdoG8CwAoa0CWATAXNBAC4LYB2A5tALzQDk9A3BgL4YbECeADgKZwwALwA8AFQB8tFBiwBtANI5y0ANZ8uAewBm0MdEh7FAXWh8AHsT7lcMAGIBXcsGLZNKgPzRyfAG58kQgVjD0IxExZ0VkiMUEgYeAg+cTNLa1tBBCk0dFloHgcAIxBsYAMILmdobU1NAAoKAuJCeFFJaAAyQVF4LIBKGUwsaG5+aAARPkKHajpW8QlI4egAehXhgD0vUYFJ6dmUaEVlNQ0dPXKjYNSrG3snFzdPbz8A6CCQsJNoAB9oJ1wfG0FD4uCY0HYuSGWEaDmIADo8NJ6OZmHlIawgA)